# The "tuist edit" keyword does not work while introducing "tuist" for swift project management

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, toolchain

I am studying to introduce tuist to avoid git conflict.
Referring to official document.
However, if you run the edit command after initializing the tuist, the error phrase "Couldn't find resource named Project Automation" appears

error is "Couldn't find resource named ProjectAutomation"

However, the generate keyword works normally.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. I could solve it installing with tuist version 1.40.0 and set it locally to my iOS App path project.

```
tuist install 1.40.0
tuist local 1.40.0
tuist edit
```

EDIT: This should fix your issue:

```
tuist uninstall 1.44.0 && tuist update
```